# Como atualizar um campo de uma tabela da Base de Dados usando um Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, stored-procedures

Eu basicamente tenho uma tabela de base de Dados, que tem um campo chamado `DESCRIÇÃO` e a tabela chama-se `Tabela123`

Tenho 10 registros nesta tabela, e no campo DESCRIÇÃO eu tenho as frases: ***Olá, você está bem?*** se repetindo por quatro vezes, ***adeus e obrigado*** quatro vezes e ***bom dia*** por duas vezes.

Eu quero mudar essas frases usando uma stored procedure.

Na primeira frase que eu quero mudar para **Exemplo: Olá, você está bem?** todos os quatros registros, na segunda frase quero mudar para ***Olá e obrigado*** nos quatro registos.

Eu basicamente quero criar um `Stored Procedure` que mude uma parte ou uma palavra da frase no campo de descrição.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateTable] @XKey INT, @XDescription NVARCHAR(MAX) AS BEGIN BEGIN TRANSACTION BEGIN try
SET nocount ON
UPDATE TABLE
SET Description = @VMDescription
WHERE ID = @VMKey
  COMMIT; END try BEGIN catch
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; DECLARE @errorMessage nvarchar(4000); DECLARE @errorSeverity int; DECLARE @errorState int;
SELECT @errorMessage = ERROR_PROCEDURE() + ': ' + ERROR_MESSAGE(),
       @errorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
       @errorState = ERROR_STATE(); RAISERROR(@errorMessage,@errorSeverity,@errorState); END catch END
```

Como tenho agora penso que está mal, visto que tenho com parâmetros e penso que não vou querer nada assim, quero correr a script e que faça o que tem em cima.

Comment: `update Tabela123 set Descricao = 'Olá, você está bem?' where Descricao = 'Olá, você está bem?'`...

Comment: @Marconi editei a resposta e meti como tinha, tente adicionar e alterar o meu código numa resposta por favor, que va de encontro ao que necessito, estou meio perdido

Comment: Ao meu ver sua `procedure` está correta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

São duas situações, se quiser utilizar a mesma `procedure` para isso, terá que ter mais um parâmetro e uma condição dentro, ou, fazer duas `procedures`:

**1- Adicionar o texto antes do texto atual:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateTable] @XKey INT, @XDescription NVARCHAR(MAX) 

AS BEGIN BEGIN TRANSACTION BEGIN try
SET nocount ON
UPDATE TABLE
SET Description = Concat('Por Exemplo: ',Description)
WHERE Description = 'Olá, você está bem?'
  COMMIT; END try BEGIN catch
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; DECLARE @errorMessage nvarchar(4000); DECLARE @errorSeverity int; DECLARE @errorState int;
SELECT @errorMessage = ERROR_PROCEDURE() + ': ' + ERROR_MESSAGE(),
       @errorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
       @errorState = ERROR_STATE(); RAISERROR(@errorMessage,@errorSeverity,@errorState); END catch END
```

**2- Substituir o texto atual:**

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateTable] @XKey INT, @XDescription NVARCHAR(MAX) 

AS BEGIN BEGIN TRANSACTION BEGIN try
SET nocount ON
UPDATE TABLE
SET Description = Replace(Description, 'adeus', 'olá' )
WHERE Description = 'adeus e obrigado'
  COMMIT; END try BEGIN catch
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; DECLARE @errorMessage nvarchar(4000); DECLARE @errorSeverity int; DECLARE @errorState int;
SELECT @errorMessage = ERROR_PROCEDURE() + ': ' + ERROR_MESSAGE(),
       @errorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
       @errorState = ERROR_STATE(); RAISERROR(@errorMessage,@errorSeverity,@errorState); END catch END
```

Documentação:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql

Espero ter ajudado.